# .htaccess redirect from https to http

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, ssl, https

I have a site where the SSL Certificate expired, and the hosting company have messed up, so it will take a while until I can get it fixed. So I have to change everything from https to http.

I have done everything needed on the site, so when a visitor goes to http://example.com, it works as it should. The problem is when the user writes https://example.com, which many have in their bookmarks and different links that have been posted around the web..

In my .htaccess-file I have written:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =https
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

This works on some devices and on other it doesn't. For example, it worked on my chrome after clearing app storage and cache, but it doesn't work on safari on the same computer, even after clearing cache. Any advices on how I can move forward?

Very thankful for all kind of help.

Comment: You can get SSL certificate on your own in 15 minutes or less. Even for free.

Comment: Also, that redirect needs working HTTPS in the first place, so it will not be of much help.

Comment: Thank you Dusan. It's a strange situation. My hosting service can't handle SSL-certificates if I use another nameserver than their own, and I am using DNSimple for nameserver, so my current hosting service doesn't allow me to install or use a SSL cert. The one they had for me expired yesterday, and they can't renew it they say... Very messy. Or is there a way for me to install a SSL cert without caring about my hosting provider? I am using one.com, if that's of any help..

Comment: "My hosting service can't handle...", "...current hosting service doesn't allow...", "...they can't renew...". Seems like you need to change hosting provider.

Comment: Yes Dusan, I will do that, but that will take a while and I need a quick solution now that let visitors enter our site..

Comment: Can they install the cert if you provide them with one?

Comment: No, they cant..

Comment: Is the only reason why they can't renew the cert because your DNS is hosted elsewhere?

Comment: Yes, that's the only reason. They have a built in SSL-solution in their hosting that is only possible to use if I also use their name server..

Comment: Do you have access to their DNS web console, for your domain?

Comment: Also (this might be a shot in the dark), you can try creating `NS` record for the name `_acme-challenge` (in your active DNS server, for your domain), pointing to your hosting providers DNS server.

Comment: Yes, I have access to their DNS web console. I will try the `_acme-challenge` tonight!